# Starting a GPU instance on Google Cloud Compute

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sdk

I am trying to set up a GPU instance on Google Compute Cloud like this

```
gcloud compute instances create another-ubuntu-instance \
 --maintenance-policy TERMINATE --restart-on-failure \
 --image-project=ubuntu-os-cloud \
 --image-family=ubuntu-2004-lts --machine-type=a2-highgpu-1g --zone europe-west4-b
```

but I get an error message:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create) Could not fetch resource:
 - Quota 'NVIDIA_A100_GPUS' exceeded.  Limit: 0.0 in region europe-west4.
```

even though I have a quota (I think):

[image]

So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Based on your comment you've already reached the GPU quota in that region. Have you tried to create on another region? You can check your quota again after 24 hour or your VM if created, it usually takes 24 hrs to reflect. If by any chance you are still having a problem you need to contact Google's QIR, You can check this link for request for additional quota: https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#requesting_additional_quota  , for GPU region and zones availability: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/gpu-regions-zones#gpu_regions_and_zones

Comment: thanks - but why would it shou quota usage at 0% (see picture) and still reject me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check your quotas in a particular region for active project using this command:

```
gcloud compute regions describe europe-west4 | grep -1 A100
```

To read more about GPU quotas [please see here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/create-vm-with-gpus#check-quota)

Answer (score 0):

To answer you last verification, here are some documentation that might explain the error you are experiencing.

If you are you using one of the [Google Cloud's Free](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#always-free-usage-limits) program there are limitations and conditions for each program.

For more [information](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/) regarding GPU that are available for Compute Engine and Graphics workload, also in what region and zone they are available.

And as discussed in my comment above, you can request a [quota increase](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#requesting_additional_quota) to Google